# Textarea not displaying placeholder in Python and Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python variable being returned in a textarea, however, when the variable returns nothing `none` is displayed instead of reverting back to the placeholder text.

Examples:

```
<textarea placeholder="some text">{{ variable }}</textarea>
```

Attempt:

```
<textarea placeholder="some text">
 {% if result %}
   {{ variable }}
 {% endif %}
</textarea>
```

Comment: How you passing the variable from python?

Comment: @AjayK Through my render_template that's associated with that file.

Comment: You need to share that code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good finding ,
I find another way to display but the way you are trying will not work because empty object is returning ..

You can try this way

```
    {% if result %}        
        <textarea placeholder="some text">
            {{result}} 
        </textarea>
    {% else %}               
        <textarea  placeholder="some text"></textarea>
    {% endif %}
```